# set loader to false when validation fail angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
function createAccount (obj) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      function registerSuccess (data) {


        auth.login(obj.email, obj.password)
          .success(function () {
            $location.path('/profile/' + data.data.user_id);
          });
      }

      return function registerError (data) {
        notify.message(data.message);
        $q.reject(data.message);
      }

      $http.post('v1/user/register', obj)
        .success(registerSuccess)
        .error(registerError);

      return deferred.promise;
    }

$scope.createUser = function(master){

     $scope.loading = true;
         $scope.createAccount = 'Creating Account...';

         user.createAccount(master)
             .then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data.success == true){
                    $scope.createAccount = 'Please wait..';
                }
             }).catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
                if(error.success == false){
                    $scope.createAccount = 'Creating Account';
                    $scope.loading = false;
                }
             });    
    }
```

Setting  $scope.loading = false; when validation error found that trigger from registerError. Please suggest thanks

{success: false, message: "Validation failed", errors: {…}, queryLog: Array(1), responseTime: "1311.3620281219ms"}
errors
:
email
:
["The email must be a valid email address."]
**proto**
:
Object
message
:
"Validation failed"
queryLog
:
[{…}]
responseTime
:
"1311.3620281219ms"
success
:
false

and how display the error in notify.message

Comment: can you try adding the code to set the false flag in finally block?

Comment: I'm getting nothing in user.createAccount(master)
          .then(function(data){
console.log(data);
})

Comment: Is there any problem with service I'm in return prospect

Answer (score 0):

Added code in finally block. It should work

```
    $scope.createUser = function(master){

         $scope.loading = true;
             $scope.createAccount = 'Creating Account...';

             user.createAccount(master)
                 .then(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data.success == true){
                        $scope.createAccount = 'Please wait..';
                    }
                 }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    if(error.success == false){
                        $scope.createAccount = 'Creating Account';
                        $scope.loading = false;
                    }
                 }).finally(function(){
$scope.loading = false;
});   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createAccount (obj) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      function registerSuccess (data) {


        auth.login(obj.email, obj.password)
          .success(function () {
            $location.path('/profile/' + data.data.user_id);
          });
      }

      return function registerError (data) {
        notify.message(data.message);
        $q.reject(data.message);
      }

      return $http.post('v1/user/register', obj)
        .success(registerSuccess)
        .error(registerError);

      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Add return into the http service it should work